# Current density indentity form Dirac equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

How to prove the following identity

$\bar{u}\gamma ^{\mu}u=\frac{p^\mu}{m}$

where u(p), a unit spinor, satisfies the free Dirac equation

$(\gamma\cdot p-m)u(p)=0$

Edit:
This how far I have arrived:

$\bar{u}\gamma^{\mu}u=\frac{\bar{u}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\nu u}{m}=\frac{\bar{u}[2g^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu]p_\nu u}{m}$
$=\frac{2\bar{u}p_\nu u}{m}-\bar{u}\gamma^\mu u$.
Under the assumption $\bar{u}p_\nu u = \bar{u}up_\nu= p_\nu$ the proof follows.
Is the assumption valid?

Comment: Do you mean $\gamma^{\mu} p_{\mu}u=mu$ ?

Comment: Sr, I meant:

$\gamma^\mu p_\mu u = mu$
and
$\overline{u}_s u_{s'} = 2m\delta_{ss'}$
But there is an additional factor 2.